# Dagger Android and scope

Tags: android, dependency-injection, viewmodel, dagger-2, dagger

I am following [architecture-components-samples: GithubBrowserSample](https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/tree/master/GithubBrowserSample)

I have a Viewmodel that has a dependency and is provided through constructor injection, Since App component is singleton dagger forces me to use Singleton scope only if I use any other scope for those components I get below error

> com.example.AppComponent scoped with @Singleton may not reference bindings with different scopes:

I tried this as well but still same

```
@Binds
@IntoMap
@ViewModelKey(MyViewModel::class)
@PerActivity
abstract fun bindMyViewModel(myViewModel: MyViewModel): ViewModel
```

Comment: You would have to use the same scoped modules as your component. If you need a `PerActivity` scope, you would need another component.

Comment: This might also help you. [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60141954/do-we-really-need-viewmodelfactories-and-viewmodelproviders-when-using-dagger)